# Compare Tuples value present inside a bag with a hardcoded String value

Tags: apache-pig

I have a data set with these columns:-

```
FMID,County,WIC,WICcash
```

Here is a sample of data:-

```
1002267,Douglas,Y,N
21005876,Douglas,Y,N
1001666,Douglas,N,Y
```

I have grouped the data based on County and have filtered the data based on `County = 'Douglas'`. Here is the output:

```
(Douglas,{(1002267,Douglas,Y,N),(21005876,Douglas,Y,N),(1001666,Douglas,N,Y)})
```

Now if the `WIC` and `WICcash` columns have value as `Y` then I want to take the combine count of the values from both the columns.

Here, combining `WIC` and `WICcash` columns I have 3 `Y` values, so my output will be

```
Douglas 3
```

How can I achieve this?

Below is the code that I have written till now

```
load_data = LOAD 'PigPrograms/Markets/DATA_GOV_US_Farmers_Market_DataSet.csv' USING PigStorage(',') as (FMID:long,County:chararray, WIC:chararray, WICcash:chararray);

group_markets_by_county = GROUP load_data BY County;

filter_county = FILTER group_markets_by_county BY group == 'Douglas';

DUMP filter_county;
```

Answer (score 0):

For looking inside a bag, you can use a nested-foreach.

```
A = LOAD 'input3.txt' AS (FMID:long,County:chararray, WIC:chararray, WICcash:chararray);
B = GROUP A by County;
describe B; /* B: {group: chararray,A: {(FMID: long,County: chararray,WIC: chararray,WICcash: chararray)}} */ 
C = FOREACH B {
        FILTER_WIC_Y = FILTER A by WIC == 'Y';
        COUNT_WIC_Y = COUNT(FILTER_WIC_Y);
        FILTER_WICcash_Y = FILTER A by WICcash == 'Y';
        COUNT_WICcash_Y = COUNT(FILTER_WICcash_Y);
        GENERATE group, COUNT_WIC_Y + COUNT_WICcash_Y as count;
}
dump C;
```

Or, you can replace 'Y'&'N' into 1&0 and add them up.

```
A = LOAD 'input3.txt' AS (FMID:long,County:chararray, WIC:chararray, WICcash:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FMID, County, (WIC == 'Y' ? 1 : 0 ) as wic, (WICcash == 'Y' ? 1 : 0 ) as wiccash;
C = GROUP B by County;
D = FOREACH C GENERATE group, SUM(B.wic) + SUM(B.wiccash) as count;
dump D;
```